# Detecting first or second Mouse Button Release?

Tags: c#, unity, input

I want to know how to detect if the user has released the mouse button the **first time**, **or the times after that**:

Pseudo-Code:

```
 if *first* (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
   {
       do something
   }

 if *second, third, fourth..etc.* (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
   {
       do something else
   }
```

I really have no idea on how to accomplish this. I'm sure it's pretty simple though!

Comment: You need to store the count in a separate variable yourself, then check the value of that variable.

Comment: @Draco18s I'm new to programming, I don't know how to do that sir! :)

Comment: [Programming with Variables](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/variables.html)

Comment: I see you have edited your question.  The question appears to be a new question, rather than a rephrasing/clarification of the old question.  If this is the case, you should ask a new question instead.  If not, in what way are the current answers insufficient?

Answer (score 1):

You should have private member in your class that will indicate if button was pressed for first time. You need to initialize it in starting function ( could be Awake, Start etc., read more about [execution order in Unity](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) ) as false. And then, in Update function - check it. If it is first time, the do X and set this var to true, else do Y.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ClickerClass : MonoBehaviour {
    private bool m_clicked;

    void Awake() {
        m_clicked = false;
    }

    void Update() {
        if( Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) )
        {
            if( m_clicked == false ) {
                m_clicked = true;
                // code for first time
            } else {
                // code for not first time
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer although `m_clicked` would not need to be initialized and `Awake()` can be left out.  The default of a boolean in C# will always be `false`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int ClickCount;

void Update()
{    
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
       if (ClickCount == 0)
       { 
              //First Click
              //do stuff
       }
       else 
       {
             //Not first click 
             //do stuff
       }

       ClickCount++;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the ClickCount variable will overflow once it reaches 2,147,483,648.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33936/discussion-on-answer-by-jon-detecting-first-or-second-mouse-button-release).